# Restrict user from accessing app data in android device's using cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing an Hybrid mobile App using Cordova and Ionic Framework. I am storing few downloaded images in application folder (~/Android/data/com.myapp.data) like this. I don't want user to access this files. Is there anyway to do that using Cordova?.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file ?

Comment: Yes, I am using Cordova File Plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer adding a dot before your folder name does the trick. (MyApp/.Images/Image1.jpg) will hide the Images to user. But it can be accessible if device rooted or Device allows them to see hidden files.